# How can I write to the root element?

Tags: c#, xml

When I use the following code I can write successfully to the XML file however it will write outside the root element.

```
StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Settings.xml");
XmlTextWriter xtw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);

xtw.WriteStartElement("connection");
xtw.WriteElementString("id", name);
xtw.WriteElementString("Version", "2.3.1");
xtw.WriteElementString("Server", ip_textBox.Text);
xtw.WriteElementString("Port", port_textBox.Text);
xtw.WriteElementString("Uid", user_textBox.Text);
xtw.WriteElementString("Password", pass_textBox.Text);

xtw.Close();
```

After the code runs the XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<root>

</root>
<connection><id>test</id><Version>2.3.1</Version><Server>127.0.0.1</Server><Port>3306</Port><Uid>root</Uid><Password>root</Password>
```

When it should look like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<root>
  <connection>
     <id>Test</id>
     <Version>2.3.1</Version>
     <Server>127.0.0.1</Server>
     <Port>3306</Port>
     <Uid>root</Uid>
     <Password>root</Password>
  </connection>
</root>
```

Again my question is how can I write inside the root element?

Comment: One thing you can do is open it as an `XxmlDocument` and append to the `XmlDocument.DocumentElement`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Comment: Also, your `StreamWriter` and `XmlWriter` need to be in `using` blocks. And you're appending to the file, so what did you expect?

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to XML so this is all new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you file already contains some XML (likely `<root></root>` based on sample output). Since you are using `AppendText` your XML will be *appended* to existing file instead of replacing. As result all nodes you've added are outside of root and XML is invalid.

There is no reasonable way to *insert* nodes into text file (possible, but generally hard).

If you want to generate complete XML with XmlWriter you need to re-create file and add all nodes starting from root.

Alternatively you can load existing file as XML (using `XmlDocument` or more popular `XDocument`), add nodes to "root" element and save whole file.

Comment: I had *completely forgotten* about `XDocument`, it completely eliminates the need for my `AppendChildWithText()` extension method. Upvote for sure.

Comment: Using XDocument worked for me, since it uses LINQ it's much easier to read and modify. I'm accepting this as the answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `XmlDocument`,

```
var path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\test.xml";
XmlDocument x = new XmlDocument(); 
x.Load(path);

var connection = x.CreateElement("connection");
connection.AppendChildWithText(x, "id", "Test");
connection.AppendChildWithText(x, "dtime", DateTime.Now.ToString());
// and so on, 
x.DocumentElement.AppendChild(connection);

x.Save(path);
```

`AppendChildWithText()` is and extension method:

```
public static XmlElement AppendChildWithText(this XmlElement me, XmlDocument x, string name, string value) {
  var el = x.CreateElement(name);
  el.InnerText = value;
  me.AppendChild(el);
  return el; 
}
```

Other notes:

- You *can* get the validation features of `XmlReader` if you need it, by initializing an `XmlDocument` with an instance of `XmlReader`.
- You're initial attempt failed because you were appending raw text to the file. That won't work for XML. `XmlDocument` handles the necessary functionality for you.